Why does my Ubuntu start up with the following black screen error?
/dev/sda3: clean, 377907/7831552 files, 6437337/31325184 blocks2.398015] systemd [366]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan failed with exit status 127.

With the info given here there is no way to even begin to guess the issue. It would be a good idea to review this link and edit the question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Does this answer your question? "dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting
